# Datagrid filtering column with a textbox ,caliburn.micro

Tags: wpf, datagrid, filter, filtering, caliburn.micro

i would I would like to make a filter to the column Bar Codes. 
In this columns i have a converter to convert List of Eans in string. The class is this:

```
public class EanListToStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
                  object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return String.Join("\r", ((List<Ean>)value).Select(ean => ean.Codice));
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
                              object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return NotSupportedException();
    }

    private object NotSupportedException()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

So i want that if the user write a barcodes in a **TEXTBOX**(or something else) which will filter the list of DataGrid.

```
<DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedArticle}"
            Margin="14,89,12,61" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" AutoGenerateColumns="False" x:Name="List">
   <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTextColumn Width="100" Binding="{Binding Code}" Header="Code" />
      <DataGridTextColumn Width="300" Binding="{Binding Description}" Header="Description" />
      <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Price}" Header="Price" />
      <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Ean, Converter={StaticResource EanListToString}}" Header="Bar Codes" />
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

This is view model

```
   [Export(typeof(IScreen))]
   public class BViewModel : Screen
   {
      public List<Articolo> List { get; private set; }
      public Article SelectedArticle { get; set; }

      [Import]
      WindowManager WindowManager = new WindowManager();

      public BolleViewModel()
      {
         List = recover.GetArticles();
         NotifyOfPropertyChange("List");
      }
   }
```

What i can do? Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with the View I would suggest you start by using the **DataGridTemplateColumn**, Specifally the **CellTemplate** so that you can place your own custom control in there e.g. ComboBox. From there you should then be cusomtize what controls you need and bind it up in your class

Rough example below

```
 <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Bar Codes">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Ean, Converter={StaticResource EanListToString}}"></ComboBox>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a DataGridTemplateColumn with a HeaderTemplate which has a TextBox input for filtering.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Width="80" SortMemberPath="Naam" Header="Naam">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <TextBlock>Naam</TextBlock>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Delay=200, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl }}, Path=DataContext.Filter.Naam, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>1
```

Model

```
public class Filter:INotifyPropertyChanged//Todo implement interface
{
   private string name;
   public string Name 
   {
      get{return name;}
      set{name = value; OnPropertyChanged("Name");}
   }
}
```

Comment: Ok, but give me this error : "Two-way binding requires Path or XPath."

Comment: Can you show me the {Binding .. } you are using and the code of what you are binding to? The data you are binding to must have a getter and setter to work.